# Unit test doesn't work for Spring path variable validation

Tags: spring, junit, mockmvc, javax-validation

I'm setting up an unit test to ensure that controller method's path variable javax constraints are working as expected with all the required dependencies.

Controller class :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("users")
@Validated
@Slf4j
public class UserSearchController

   @GetMapping(value = "/search/{phone}", produces = {"application/json"})
   public Mono<ResponseEntity<SearchResult>> searchUsersByPhoneNumber(@PathVariable("phone")
                                                                      @NotBlank(message = "Number must not be empty")
                                                                      @Pattern(regexp = "^\\+44\\d{10}$", message = "Invalid phone number. Must be in E.164 format.")
                                                                      String phone) {
    return service.searchByPhoneNumber(phone)
                              .map(ResponseEntity::ok);
  }
}
```

Test Class :

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class UserSearchControllerTest {

  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @InjectMocks
  private UserSearchController userSearchController;

  @BeforeEach
  public void setup() {
    JacksonTester.initFields(this, new ObjectMapper());
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(userSearchController)
                             .setControllerAdvice(new RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler())
                             .build();
  }


  @Test
  public void testSearchByPhoneNumber_InvalidInput_ReturnsBadRequest() throws Exception {
    String INVALID_PHONE_NUMBER = "1234567890";
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/users/search/{phone}", INVALID_PHONE_NUMBER))
                                      .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isBadRequest());
   }

}
```

`RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler` is configured to handle exceptions thrown by the controller.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {ConstraintViolationException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConstraintViolation(ConstraintViolationException ex, WebRequest request) {
       // returning error response
    }
```

This setup is working as expected and constraints are validated correctly in case `phone` path variable is not in the expected format. However, unit test is not working as expected, it fails the validation and starting to execute the `searchUsersByPhoneNumber` without throwing the exception and end up giving a null pointer exception for `service.searchByPhoneNumber(phone)` line. What might be causing this?

Comment: You aren't using Spring to create the controller but rather Mockito, which doesn't know what to do with those annotations. Use `@WebMvcTest` instead.